# Pasar valor de arreglo a query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy tratando de pasar un valor de mi arreglo a mi query pero al momento de hacerlo me dice:

> Array to string conversion

Mi arreglo proviene de una función en un archivo llamado `functions.php`

Es el primer valor de mi arreglo el que quiero pasar al query de  mi archivo functions.php

Tengo una variable que recoje el resultado de mi función principal:

```
$emit = obtener_mensajes($conexion, $us);
```

Aquí es donde quiero insertar mi query y la variable:

```
<?php 

$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE idEmitter IN ($us, $emit[0]) AND idReceiver IN ($emit[0], $us) ORDER BY sent ASC" ;

$run = $conexion->query($query);

while ($row = $run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
    //var_dump($row);

?>
```

Este es mi arreglo

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(10) {
    ["idEmitter"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que te está indicando es que estás intentando insertar un array directamente en la consulta.

Esto se debe a que a pesar de que tu accedes a la primera posición del array `$emit`, este a su vez tiene un array contenido en dicha posición, por lo que tendrías que acceder a las claves asociativas de este segundo array para acceder a cada uno de sus valores y poderlos incluir en tu consulta.

Ejemplo:

```
$emit[0]["idEmitter"];
$emit[0][0];
```

Comment: entiendo lo que me dices que tengo que hacer, mas no se me ocurre una idea de como hacerlo :/

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos ¿Cómo quieres insertar los valores en tu consulta? ¿El que no sabes como hacer? Deberías de sustituir los valores que tienes actualmente por cualquiera de los dos que están contenidos dentro de tu array.

Comment: listo, introduje el php que contiene el query dentro de un `foreach`, no se si esa sea una buena practica

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos Yo creo que cambiando `$emit[0]` por `$emit[0]["idEmitter"]` debería de bastar para tu problema.

Comment: cuando lo pongo de esa manera me marca el siguiente error `syntax error, unexpected 'idEmitter' `

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos Ponlo con comillas simples ya que si no estás cerrando las comillas dobles. Ponlo así: `$emit[0]['idEmitter']`

Comment: me temo que el error perciste, aunque con el foreach funciona a la perfeccion

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos Igual no estoy entendiendo bien el problema que te está generando aunque me alegro que hayas podido solucionarlo :)